# problem creating file file in apache druid

Tags: mkdir, druid

I am using apache-druid-28.0.0 single server micro_quickstart.

I submit the task spec with tutorial transform-index.json. however, I want to load data from /tmp/test directory instead of quickstart directory. So I changed baseDir in task spec. However, I got the following error --
"Mkdirs failed to create file:/druid/segments/test_load_local_disk"

Please let me know what I did wrong. I pasted my task spec below

{
"type" : "index_parallel",
"spec" : {
"dataSchema" : {
"dataSource" : "test_load_local_disk",
"timestampSpec": {
"column": "timestamp",
"format": "iso"
},
"dimensionsSpec" : {
"dimensions" : [
"animal",
{ "name": "location", "type": "long" }
]
},
"metricsSpec" : [
{ "type" : "count", "name" : "count" },
{ "type" : "longSum", "name" : "number", "fieldName" : "number" },
{ "type" : "longSum", "name" : "triple-number", "fieldName" : "triple-number" }
],
"granularitySpec" : {
"type" : "uniform",
"segmentGranularity" : "week",
"queryGranularity" : "minute",
"intervals" : ["2018-01-01/2018-01-03"],
"rollup" : true
},
"transformSpec": {
"transforms": [
{
"type": "expression",
"name": "animal",
"expression": "concat('super-', animal)"
},
{
"type": "expression",
"name": "triple-number",
"expression": "number * 3"
}
],
"filter": {
"type":"or",
"fields": [
{ "type": "selector", "dimension": "animal", "value": "super-mongoose" },
{ "type": "selector", "dimension": "triple-number", "value": "300" },
{ "type": "selector", "dimension": "location", "value": "3" }
]
}
}
},
"ioConfig" : {
"type" : "index_parallel",
"inputSource" : {
"type" : "local",
"baseDir" : "/tmp/test",
"filter" : "transform-data.json"
},
"inputFormat" : {
"type" : "json"
},
"appendToExisting" : false
},
"tuningConfig" : {
"type" : "index_parallel",
"maxRowsPerSegment" : 5000000,
"maxRowsInMemory" : 25000
}
}
}